# How to add multiple css property with same name in react?

Tags: reactjs, class-names

I am using react and came across a situation where I needed a fallback CSS property.

Normal CSS code:

```
.grid{
  position:sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

Currently, I am getting it done by using two different classes and adding both the classes to the component (using `classnames` library).
Like this:

```
<Grid className={classnames(c1,c2)}/>
```

where `c1` and `c2` both have position property but with different values.

My question being that am I doing it in the right manner? If not, Is there any workaround?

Comment: Check this out - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839356/how-can-i-apply-fallback-style-properties-to-a-react-js-component)

Comment: thanks, @simplecreator, guess I have to use the current approach coz others are no good than this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
.c1{
  position:sticky;
}
.c2{
  position:-webkit-sticky;
}
```

The browser will apply what it suports. I never worked with React, but I'm pretty sure there'd a better way to write the fall-back properties.

Comment: no, you cannot do that in JCSS as it is a js object and cannot store keys with the same name.